# Android - Unknown scene name: translate exception - when starting activity with transition

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity, android-animation

I'm trying to set up the animation of the appearance of the activity, but when the activity starts, the exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown scene name: translate" is thrown.

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.createtarget.CreateTargetActivity" android:theme="@style/SlidingPanel"/>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="SlidingPanel" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/slide_from_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/slide_to_bottom</item>
</style>
```

Activity layout xml:

```
android:theme="@style/SlidingPanel"
```

Transition xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

If it matters, I start the activity from the fragment like this:

```
private fun onCreateNewTask(){
        val intent = Intent(context, CreateTargetActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("targetPosition",targetPosition)
        startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity).toBundle())
    }
```

Please tell me how I can fix this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Transition XML is not a valid Transition - that's a [View Animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#View) XML file, not a transition (you'd apply view animations via [`overridePendingTransition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) called after you call `startActivity`)

As per the [Start an activity using a transition guide](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity), you need to use one the types listed there. In your case, it looks like you should be using a [Slide Transition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Slide) with the `Gravity.START` edge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:slideEdge="start">
</slide>
```

Comment: Note that you can [search the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/transition/TransitionInflater.java;l=181?q=%22Unknown%20scene%20name%22) for your particular error message, which often can help figure out your issue.